# Use of Unresolved Identifier adding second pin MapKit swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to add another pin to my map.
It has worked fine with

```
 artworkPin = Artwork(title:"Wind      Wand",locationName:"Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                             coordinate:windwandcoord)
```

but now I've tried adding

```
artworkPin2 = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand2",locationName:" Not Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                         coordinate:windwandcoord2)
```

but this is giving me an error of **Use of unresolved identifier 'artworkPin2'**

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means there is no variable named `artworkPin2` in the current scope.

So assuming you are creating a new, local variable, you need to use `var` (or `let`):

```
var artworkPin2 = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand2",locationName:" Not Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                     coordinate:windwandcoord2)
```

Or perhaps you need to add a property named `artworkPin2` to your class and assign to that property.

Comment: Ah I see, I think the reason the first one is not defined as `let/var artworkPin` is because above it is defined as `var artworkPin:Artwork!`

Comment: Do you know how I can use my segue to take the title of any pin to be the label on the next UI View? I currently have it setup like this (http://pastebin.com/pVguuBuX)  But this will only transfer the title of first pin (artworkPin) however I want it to transfer the relevant title for any pin, e.g: artworkPin2

Comment: That's a completely different question. If this answer solved this question, please mark the answer accepted. If you have a new question, please post a new question with all relevant code (in the question, not as a link) and details. But be sure you do some basic research first.

Comment: Sorry it was solved too quickly and it said I had to wait before I clicked 'solved' thanks for your help anyway. What research can you recommend? I am not really sure how to word my question